# sqlite installation

Tags: installation, sqlite

I'm installing sqlite like this [SQLite - Installation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm)

I get this error, anyone know what to do?

```
anonymous@Anonymous:~/sqlite-autoconf-3080001$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/anonymous/sqlite-autoconf-3080001'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsqlite3.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anonymous/sqlite-autoconf-3080001'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
anonymous@Anonymous:~/sqlite-autoconf-3080001$
```

Sorry I don't know the proper way of putting it in

Answer (score 27):

It should be

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You could install it through the repo's

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: you are right sir

Comment: I would like to add that if you need to have the sqlite driver (for example, to use it along with Doctrine) or wish to enable sqlite for php, please run in the terminal `apt-get install php5-sqlite`

Comment: Probably slightly off topic, but apptitude warns me about not being able to authenticate this package. Is that just in my case? I am wondering how can this be the case with sqlite (quite popular).

Comment: never mind, I understood what was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use `sudo apt-get install sqlite` and it will recognize and install all dependencies and related packages for sqlite to work properly.

Comment: It will install sqlite version 2 unless you use `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

`sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` for PHP 5.5

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-sqlite` for PHP 5.6

Comment: who said anything about PHP?

Comment: It is a way of installing sqlite if you need to install the PHP library too. I believe these commands have a dependency on sqlite and will include it as a dependency. Been a long time but I think that is why I posted it as an answer.